# PHP AND SOAP. Change envelope

Tags: php, soap, envelope

It is many questions there about PHP and SOAP. But I am not found answer on my situation.

So. I use PHP SoapClient and WSDL for it. Object sends this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.site.com"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

But I need this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body>
```

Question. How I can do this with standard PHP class SoapClient?

Thank you.

Comment: I think that means your WSDL is incorrect? Did you create the SOAP server piece also?

Comment: No, WSDL is correct, because other library (ActiveX control for C#) works with it good and send true namespace.
I can't change SOAP-server. I need use it to access to service functions.

Comment: If you think this is causing an issue in communicating with your SOAP service, this may be an incorrect assumption. Your error may be related to missing properties in your message, as has just happened to me.

Answer (score 5):

I search answer in php.net

```
<?php
class MSSoapClient extends SoapClient {

    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) {
        $namespace = "http://tempuri.com";

        $request = preg_replace('/<ns1:(\w+)/', '<$1 xmlns="'.$namespace.'"', $request, 1);
        $request = preg_replace('/<ns1:(\w+)/', '<$1', $request);
        $request = str_replace(array('/ns1:', 'xmlns:ns1="'.$namespace.'"'), array('/', ''), $request);

        // parent call
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
    }
}

$client = new MSSoapClient(...);
?>
```

This code change Envelope in request. And need for ASP SOAP server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SoapVar::typeNamespace` for set your `xmlns:xsi`

something like this :

```
new SoapVar($data, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "Type", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

source : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/soapvar.construct